# Excel 2013 VBA User Populated Array from Filtered List

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a VBA routine created (using Macro Record) to copy products and quantities to a new sheet using filtering on two columns. This works fine, but I would like to allow the user to select items and quantities from two filtered lists and add them to two arrays which are then copied to a new sheet.

The Quantity Array could be simplified as it is just the quantities associated with the Manufacturer Array that are not equal to zero

Code segment;

```
intCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

Sheets("Materials").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$I$524").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Castel", "CEM", "Honeywell", "TYCO"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$I$524").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "1.00", "10.00", "100.00", "2.00", "20.00", "24.00", "35.00", "4.00", "43.00", "5.00", _
    "96.00"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I would assume that each array element needs to defined as a variable and then passed to the array. I can't figure out how to present what to filter to the user. Create a user form and populate with the all the manufacturers? What is the most efficient method of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Either (1) you set the first filter and copy what you have to the new sheet (which you mentioned is working already) and then set the filter to something new and simply append the new result set to the end of the new sheet or (2) you "save" the result sets to an array in memory and then dump the arrays one after the other to the new sheet. The result is the same.

So, it would seem to me that option 1 should be easy for you. Option 2 is as easy as option 1. Just dim a variant variable and assign it the range you wish you store in memory:

```
Dim vArray As Variant

vArray = Sheets("Materials").Range("A3:I524")  'the range you wish to copy
```

Am I missing the point or is this what you need?

Comment: Having thought more on this, essentially I want a dialog box to be populated with each manufacturer located in col B. The user then selects which ones to filer on using check boxes. These are fed to the Materials array. The Qty array will consist of any non zero quantity for each row displayed

Comment: So, basically you are no longer interested in a solution to the problem you posted above?